# onFocus and onBlur not getting called on Android tv

Tags: android, react-native, android-tv

I am building android tv app using react native, `onFocus` and `onBlur` are getting called on android tv emulator but not on real android tv. I am using `TouchableOpacity` for which `onFocus` and `onBlur` are props.

I don't know what is the reason. it is working in emulator but not in real android tv.

```
<TouchableOpacity onFocus={()=>{console.log("called onfocus")}} onBlur={()=>{
console.log("called onblur")
}}> 
....
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, We had to rewrite whole navigation in react-native for that to work properly.

Comment: I actually found my problem, I used regular react-native and for onFocus and onBlur to work you have to use this: https://github.com/react-native-tvos/react-native-tvos

Comment: Glad you found solution.